# Dimension of the set of solutions to a linear second order homogeneous differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

So I am trying to prove that a linear second order homogeneous differential equation has a solution of the form 
$$c_1 e^{m_1 x} + c_2e^{m_2 x}$$
(for real and distinct roots of the auxillary equation, where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the roots).

1)So I begin with constructing a vector space 
$$X=\{f(x): \, f(x) \textrm{ is a solution to the differential equation} \}$$

Then I need to show that this vector is of $2$ dimensions. I can't seem to figure out how to prove that the vector space has two dimensions.

2)Once that is done, we can show that $e^{m_1 x}$ and $e^{m_2 x}$ are spanning vectors with linear independence. Also since we should have by now proved that dimensions of the space is $2$, they form a complete basis set.

Hence, any vector in the space can be represented as a linear combination of the two basis vectors. Which proves that a linear 2nd order homogeneous differential equation has a solution of the form $c_1 e^{m_1 x} + c_2e^{m_2 x}$, with $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must consider the equation

$y’’+a_1y’+a_2y=0$

with initial conditions $y’(t_0)=m_1$ and $y(t_0)=m_2$.

You can observe that by Cauchy theorem there exists a unique solution of your equation in a neighborhoods of $t_0$. By some theorems of extension of solutions you have that you can extend your unique solution to all $\mathbb{R}$. In this way you get that it is possibile define a bijective  map

$\Psi: \mathbb{R}^2\to X$

such that for each couple $(m_1,m_2)$ we consider the solution of the differential equation $\Psi(m_1,m_2)$ of that initial data. 
You can observe that the map $\Psi$ is linear because the equation is linear. So the map $\Psi$ is an isomorphism and $X$ has dimension 2.

If you want, you can generalize the result to a generic omogeneus equation of degree $n$ using the same argument.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why you have taken an initial condition. m1 and m2 are simply the roots to the auxillary equation. Can you please help me out if I'm missing something?

Comment: you consider the set X of solution and that set is defined by a couple of elements of R, because if you fixed the initial data then you get only one solution that it is in X. By other way it is obvious that each solution in X is a solution of the equation with a specific initial conditions.